Zarr: KeyError .zarray when opening anndata group
When I try to open an anndata group object with zarr using a store:
group = zarr.group(store=self._store)

I get a keyError on .zarray. zarr is trying to figure out if certain folders are arrays or groups. How can I avoid this. Following alternatives didn't solve the problem as well:
group = zarr.open_group(store=self._store, mode='r')
group = zarr.Group(store=self._store, path='/', read_only=True)

